# What is the tension exerted at an arbitrary point on a hot air balloon?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics, kinetic-theory

To create a hot air balloon, one would need an envelope to hold the hot gasses, a heat source to heat the gasses with and a load to carry.

Due to the pressure difference between the inside and outside of the envelope, the material doesn't need to be stiff, but it must not fail under tension.  This tension at any given spot will be related to the pressure difference between the inside and outside of the envelope, the weight of the envelope that is below pulling on it, and the weight of the load.

Assuming a spherical envelope, how does one calculate the maximum tension that the envelope must be able to take and how does that tension vary over the surface of the envelope?

I would think that the maximum tension would be at the top of the envelope as it would be pulled from all directions along the surface and the minimum at the bottom.  However, I'm not sure if the tension variation would be necessarily linearly proportional to height, but I'm having difficulty with the mental simulation.  If I were to take a strip of the envelope from top to bottom, it would only be the weight directly below that which tension would be based on, but doesn't the strip beside it also support it, or does symmetry cancel out forces of adjacent strips?

As an aside, am I correct that is the pressure difference at any given height going to be the same regardless of the temperature difference?

Comment: The tension at any point in a membrane depends on the pressure difference across it, and the local radius of curvature. If the radius of curvature varies (i.e. the shape is not a sphere) the change in tension can be balanced by a shear force, for example tension in a rope fixed to the membrane and supporting the payload of the balloon.

Comment: That looks like a difficult calculation. Have you tried to do it? Where are you getting stuck? ... How is the load distributed over the surface of the balloon?

Comment: @sammygerbil, I'm way out of my depth here.  I'm not even sure where to start.  The last physics course I took was first year university 20+ years ago.  I'm assuming the load is below the sphere like a hanging basket for now.

Comment: What is your motivation? You are asking about a calculation. The details of the model seem vague. If this is a personal goal then you need to dust off your textbooks and get stuck in. If you have a practical application in mind then building a scale model might be more appropriate. A calculation is going to be difficult and will require you to be much more specfic about your model. Is it going to be worth the effort?

Comment: Even assuming a spherical baloon, where the load below is supported by a kind of net over the top part of the membrane, it seems too complicated.

Comment: If it floats, the sum of atmospheric pressure on the top part + load pressure, also supported by the top part + the weight of the membrane + the weight of the air inside, are balanced by the upwards atmospheric pressure on the bottom part. Too many variables.

Comment: It was easy if the tension on the membrane was only a function of internal and external pressure, baloon radius and membrane thickness.